# Unique words counter using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function uniqueWordCount which can count all unique words in a string (words.txt). I should be able to get the answer after returning it, and I have done something like this now:

```
let fs = require('fs');

function run() {
  let text = fs.readFileSync('./words.txt', 'utf8');
  return uniqueWordCount(text);
}

function uniqueWordCount(str) { 

  let count = 0;

  let set = new Set();

  let words = str.split (' ');

  for(let i = 1; 1 < words.length; i++){
    set.add(str[i]);
    count = set.size;
  }

  return uniqueWordCount;
}


module.exports.run = run;
```

Comment: Please review the answers below and mark one as correct if it helped you

Answer (score 4):

split the string on spaces using `split()` and make it a set. Set will remove the duplicates. Return the size of the set using `size()`

```js
function uniqueWordCount(str) { 
  let set = new Set(str.split(' '));
  return set.size;
}
console.log(uniqueWordCount('as as de we re'))
```

Answer (score 0):

An ES5 & ES6 compliant solution could be:

```
"aabc      adsd adsd hasd"
.split(/\b(?:\s+)?/)
.reduce(function(ac,d,i){!~ac.indexOf(d) && ac.push(d);return ac;},[]).length //return 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple regex solution:**

```
function uniqueWordCount(text) {
    return new Set(text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w\s]+/u, "").split(" ")).size;
}
```

**Problems with different solutions you may encounter:**

- Case sensitivity - Cat and cat are the same words, toLowerCase() will help.
- Punctuation - "Cat" and "Cat," are the same words, removing non-word characters will help
- Character encoding when using regex, /u (unicode) flag will help with cyrillic and nordic letters

**Regex explained:**

- /u - unicode flag is needed, othewise only english letters work
- [^\w\s]+ - remove any non-word and non-space
- \w - shortcut for a-zA-Z0-9, but /u extends this. /[a-z]/u does not include foreign letters.

Javascript Set object acts as a unique dictionary, adding any existing word in it will be ignored.

Comment: This should work the same way, but 'cat-cat cat' would return 1 instead of 2:

return new Set(text.toLowerCase().match(/\w+/gu)).size;

Answer (score -1):

```js
function uniqueWordCount(str) {
  var i = [];
  return str.split(' ')
          .map( e => (i[e] === undefined) ? i[e] = 1 : 0)
          .reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);
}

console.log(uniqueWordCount("ws ws ws we we wf h"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are 4 changes you have to make to get your `uniqueWordCount` function to work:

1. Start your `for-loop` at `let i = 0`, not `let i = 1`
2. `1 < words.length` will ALWAYS be true, creating an infinite loop. Replace `1` with `i` -> `i < words.length`
3. In your `for-loop` access `words[i]`, not `str[i]` since `words` is your array of words, `str` is just your original string.
4. You're returning a variable `uniqueWordCount` which is a function, but you need to return `count` which is storing the `size` of your set.

Here is how your function should now look:

```
function uniqueWordCount(str) { 

  let count = 0;

  let set = new Set();

  let words = str.split (' ');

  // 1. replace 'let i = 1;' with 'let i = 0;'
  // 2. replace the second condition 1 < words.length with i < words.length
  for(let i = 1; i < words.length; i++){
    // 3. replace 'str[i]' with 'words[i]'
    set.add(words[i]);
    count = set.size;
  }

  // 4. change 'uniqueWordCount' to 'count'
  return count;
}
```

Note: You can and probably should get rid of your `count` variable and just return `set.size` at the end of your function. Then you will be able to avoid updating `count` on every iteration of your `for-loop` as well. This change is not *required* but would make your function nicer. Here is how it would look:

```
function uniqueWordCount(str) { 

  let set = new Set();

  let words = str.split (' ');

  for(let i = 1; i < words.length; i++){
    set.add(words[i]);
  }

  return set.size;
}
```

One final optimization would be similar to what @ellipsis mentioned - creating a `Set` immediately while splitting your `str` string. Like this:

```
function uniqueWordCount(str) { 

  // automatically populate your 'Set'
  let set = new Set(str.split (' '));

  // immediately return your set's size
  return set.size;
}
```

**Note**: If you want to count unique words regardless of case, you can immediately do `str.toLowerCase()` in your `uniqueWordCount` function.

Comment: @Jwei1010 I hadn't noticed the other flaws - check my updated answer